# How to get the name of java file if its name was changed in a commit?

Tags: git

Imagine some changes were made to file A in commit 1 and now in commit 2 the file name was changed to file B.

I would like to know the git command to get the actual file name of file B in the previous commit.

My use is to get the original file name of a particular file for before a particular commit. e.g for my research I need to get a particular file(file B) of a  particular commit plus the same file of the previous commit. I was successfully in getting the previous commit number and get the file details for that commit.But for few files, the file name gets changed from file A to file B so if i try to use git show previous_commit:fille B , it will give error because in that commit the actual name of file was A. So for this i need to figure out some ways of getting the original name of file B before a particular commit.

Answer (score 1):

git log --follow --name-only B

(Only works for one file at a time. See "git help log".)

Comment: My use is to get the original file name of a particular file for before a particular commit.

Comment: tried it but i was getting list of all changes for that file ...How can i just get the original name ?

Comment: I don't know a command to give you *just* the name. With both of those flags you should get the name as well as the changes.

Comment: it seems to work if you just print that last line:
git log  --follow --oneline --name-only file | tail -n 1